# Preparing a funding proposal for a year in Montreal

Tags: canada, sweden, costs

I'm writing a funding proposal for a year of travel in Montreal and potentially Sweden, and I need to budget all the expenses I could possibly have during this time (the funding is to fully support all expenses). How would one go about constructing a thorough budget? What are unexpected expenses that typically crop up?